# How do I prove the following for the given congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If I have prime($x$) s.t,  $x\equiv 5\mod 8$,

How can I prove that $$xa^2 + 6b^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3x $$
has no solutions? I know this will involve Legendre  somehow but since $8$ is not an odd prime I don't know how to proceed further

Comment: $x$ is prime? a confusing choice of notation!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach. I will use $p$ instead of $x$ to express as a prime. Since $p \equiv 5 \mod 8$, $p \neq 3$. Let assume that the equation is solvalbe for $a, b$. From the equation, one has a systems of congruence:
\begin{equation}
    pa^2 + 6b^2 \equiv 1 \mod p \tag 1 \\
pa^2 + 6b^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3 
\end{equation}
For the second equation in $(1)$, we infer $pa^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ because $3| \space 6$. Moreover, having $a^2 \equiv \{0, 1\}\mod 3$, we obtain $p \equiv 1\mod 3$, with the fact that $p$ is odd, we conclude $p \equiv 1 \mod 6$.

Now, for the first equation, which is equivalent to $6b^2 \equiv 1 \equiv 5p + 1 \mod p$. Having $5p + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 6$, yeids:
$$b^2 \equiv \frac{5p+1}{6} \mod p\Rightarrow \left(\frac{\frac{5p+1}{6}}{p}\right) = 1$$
By Euler's criterion:
$$ \left(\frac{5p+1}{6}\right)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \mod p \Rightarrow 6^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv (5p+1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 1 \mod p  $$
Therefore:
$$\left(\frac{6}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{2}{p}\right) \left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = 1 \tag 2$$
However, since $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$, by Gauss reciprocity law and addition property:
\begin{equation}
   \left(\frac{3}{p}\right)  \left(\frac{p}{3}\right) = \left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{(p-1)(3-1)}{4}} = 1 \\
\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}} = (-1)
\end{equation}
The last equality holds because $p \equiv 5 \mod 8$. This contradicts $(2)$. $\square$